# Как извлечь из датафрейма адреса с помощью библиотеки Natasha

Tags: python, dataframe, natasha

У меня имеется датафрейм. С помощью библиотеки `Natasha` мне необходимо извлечь адреса и очистить от лишних данных, таких как Match(start=1, stop=7, fact=Addr и оставить только название города/улицы. В сети нашел это решение:

```
from natasha import AddrExtractor, MorphVocab
morph_vocab = MorphVocab()
extractor = AddrExtractor(morph_vocab)
text = "г Калининград, ул Гагарина,20"
matches = extractor(text)
for match in matches:
    address = text[match.start:match.stop]
print(address)
```

однако, оно работает только для строковых данных и выдает последнее совпадение (ул Гагарина).Подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать данный код для dataframe.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код исходного датафрейма

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'Bob', ' москва'],
                  [2,'Sally', 'отдых'],
                  [3,'Scott', ' хабаровск']], 
columns=['id','name', 'street'])
df
```

Ожидаемый результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы сначала создаете переменную `addr_extractor`, а потом пытаетесь обратиться к ней по имени `extractor`

Comment: Приведите датафрейм не картинкой, а в воспроизводимом виде, т.е. что-то вроде `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'name': ['Bob', 'Sally', 'Scott']})`. И ещё приведите пример - что вы хотите получить на выходе. Примеры всегда полезны, без них бывает ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так это всё можно объединить:

```
# !pip install natasha

import pandas as pd
from natasha import AddrExtractor, MorphVocab

morph_vocab = MorphVocab()
extractor = AddrExtractor(morph_vocab)

def fix_addr(text):
    matches = extractor(text)
    return (', '.join(f'{match.fact.type or ""} {match.fact.value}' for match in matches)) or None

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'Bob', ' москва'],
                  [2,'Sally', 'отдых'],
                  [3,'Scott', 'хабаровск'], 
                  [4,'Вася', 'село Верхний Низ, ул. Ленина, д. 17']],  
columns=['id','name', 'street'])
df['street1'] = df['street'].map(fix_addr)
df
```

| index | id | name | street | street1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Bob | москва | москва |
| 1 | 2 | Sally | отдых | None |
| 2 | 3 | Scott | хабаровск | хабаровск |
| 3 | 4 | Вася | село Верхний Низ, ул. Ленина, д. 17 | село Верхний Низ, улица Ленина, дом 17 |

В вашем коде показывает только последний найденный элемент адреса из-за неправильной табуляции, нужно внести `print` в цикл, вот так:

```
for match in matches:
    address = text[match.start:match.stop]
    print(address) # <- правильная табуляция
```

Теперь напечатает все фрагменты. Ну и брать элемент можно проще, как у меня в коде выше, через `match.fact.value`, а не через срез. Ещё там есть `match.fact.type` с типом элемента (например, "город"), но он не всегда заполнен.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сработало.